# ECHO specific row from specific column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my situation:

I am building a multi language page where my language come out of MYSQL through a PDO statement. The language is selected through an ID inside my link.

For Example:

```
<div class="country"><a class="darkbrowntext" href="log?id=11111">
<div class="language"><p>Nederlands</p></div>
<div class="countryflag"><img src="images/Dutch.gif" width="220" height="145" alt="dutch"></div>
</a></div>

<div class="country"><a class="darkbrowntext" href="log?id=11112">
<div class="language"><p>English</p></div>
<div class="countryflag"><img src="images/english.gif" width="220" height="145" alt="french"></div>
</a></div>
```

On my log page i have the following code:

```
$languageid = (int) $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($languageid)){
        $_SESSION['languageid'] = $languageid;
    }
    else {
        header('Location: error');
    }
require('incl/connect.inc.php');

if(isset($languageid) && ($languageid == 11111)){
    $column = 'language_nl';
}
elseif(isset($languageid) && ($languageid == 11112)){
    $column = 'language_en';
}
$languagestmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT $column FROM attrib_language");
$languagestmt->execute();
$lrow = $languagestmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If a have this table in my MYSQL:

```
ID       language_nl       language_en
1        Aanmelden         Sign in
2        Afmelden          Sign out
3        Naam              Name
4        Voornaam          First name
```

How will I be able to select the right thing in my array of my column to put it into the right labels see below. Do I have to work with foreach or do I have to change my fetch?

```
<div class="logtxt"><a href="form"><h3><?php echo $lrow['***********']; ?></h3></a></div>
<div class="logtxt"><a href="logout"><h3><?php echo $lrow['***********']; ?></h3></a></div>
<label for="name" class="labelname"><?php echo $lrow['***********']; ?></label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inputname" onclick="fncCheck();"/>
<label for="firstname" class="labelfirstname"><?php echo $lrow['***********']; ?></label><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="inputfirstname" onclick="fncCheck();"/>
```

Comment: This question is not a good fit, unless you simplify your code to 2-6 lines and give a more generic example. For example, remove ALL HTML from your question, it is not relevant to PHP+MySQL questions.

Comment: And that is why you are increasing my reputation? Unbelievable. There are time you can't give enough information and there are times like now i believe you give to much?? I am selflearning to handle PHP, MYSQL & PDO it's not that i am a PRO

Comment: if u tag your question mysql+php , there is no reason to have HTML in the code example. That is true 100% of the times, unless you tag it wrongly. In which case, have only front end code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$languagestmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT ID,$column FROM attrib_language");


$lrow = $languagestmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN || PDO::FETCH_GROUP, 0);


<?php echo $lrow[1]; ?>
```

or

```
$languagestmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT language_en,$column FROM attrib_language");


$lrow = $languagestmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN || PDO::FETCH_GROUP, 0);


<?php echo $lrow['Sign In']; ?>
```

Whichever you prefer.

Comment: I suppose if i chose the second solution i am not very dynamic? For example if i choose Nederlands (dutch) than there would still be written 'Sign In'?

Comment: The variable $lrow['Sign In'] will contain 'Aanmelden' if you managed to set $column to language_nl before executing the statement. You are dynamic, unless you have multiple strings containing the same values in english, but different values in nederlands. `5 Exit Afstappen` and `6 Exit Uitgang` may be such a case, where you would prefer the first version, using IDs.

Comment: Thank u i've used your solution the only thing i had to remove was:  $lastid = $_SESSION['lastid'];  then it worked like a charm!

Comment: Sorry about that (my edit), I can do a rollback if you want to bring it back the way you had it. @Alexander - There was a lot of space between the lines, so I figured I would reduce them.

Comment: However, you should have put a comment in your code in order to illustrate what needed to be done. I.e.: `// there are lines to put in between these three...` @Alexander - There was no indication of that in your original answer, so I won't take the full blame on this one. If you have additional instructions to give the OP, then please do write them in. You shouldn't expect the OP to "figure it out". ;-)

Comment: I did a rollback. Now it's back the way you wrote it. Next time, leave comments in your code. `// comment` @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = $db->prepare ("SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table");
$res->execute();
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
   echo $row['a'] . $row['b'],$row['c'];
}
```

Notice the `$row` is an associative array where the members are the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you `print_r($lrow);` or `var_dump($lrow);` to see your results in what shape or form. Also to have a cleaner view, `echo "<pre>";` before it.

Answer (score 0):

[PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

So it should be:

```
<div class="logtxt"><a href="form"><h3><?php echo $lrow[$column][1]; ?></h3></a></div>
<div class="logtxt"><a href="logout"><h3><?php echo $lrow[$column][2]; ?></h3></a></div>
<label for="name" class="labelname"><?php echo $lrow[$column][3]; ?></label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inputname" onclick="fncCheck();"/>
<label for="firstname" class="labelfirstname"><?php echo $lrow[$column][4]; ?></label><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="inputfirstname" onclick="fncCheck();"/>
```

However, if I were you I would store each of the translations in a different file (utf-8 encoded) instead of a database.

Comment: Can i ask what you mean with your last sentence? I always learn't that the most CMS systems are build upon entries inside MYSQL instead of hard coded? So they are able tho "UPDATE" this entries a easy way? The next thing i would like to do/learn is to make a little CMS on this way.

Comment: He means to put the thing in a file, not a database. Database always means overhead, and if you only update your language files every now and then, a file could be better. But, this is only true if it really is every now and then, for daily updates a db could be better. If your database may be down, but the web server still running, you can even give multi-language error messages if you use a file.

Comment: I mean that you should use the tools for what they are good for. What you are doing here is just text replacement. You do not need a database for that. Furthermore, if you use a database for this feature, you will have to provide a UI, whereas if the translation is done through files, you can tell your users to update those files directly without a UI. At the top of my head Wordpress (but in a circumvoluted way) and Moodle use flat files for translations.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that could be very useful (To remember). For now i would like to use through a database if i am in a bit further stage i would definitely want to try the other way! thank you very much!

Comment: Could you post a print_r or a var_dump of lrow? - What is happening is that PHP select the first character, second character and so on of the returned row value.